# Does $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} xy^4 / (x^2 + y^8)$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

From [this question](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120207202732AAN1D3V) on answers.yahoo, the guy says the following limit does not exist:
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy^4}{x^2 + y^8},$$
 then on [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+%28x%2Cy%29-%3E%280%2C0%29+xy%5E4+%2F+%28x%5E2+%2B+y%5E8%29), it says the limit is equal to $0$. When I did it myself, I tried approaching $(0,0)$ from the $x$-axis, $y$-axis, $y=x$, $y=x^2$. They all equal $0$.

But when I tried the squeeze theorem, I got $y^8 \leq x^2 + y^8$, therefore $0 \leq |xy^4/(x^2+y^8)| \leq |\dfrac{x}{y^4}|$, and the latter does not exist for $(x, y) \to (0,0)$.

So does the original limit exist or not? I'm getting contradicting information from various sources. Also, if it doesn't exist (it looks like it doesn't... I think), how would I go about proving that it doesn't?

Comment: One example more (already close to 10 just in the last 4-5 months that I can remember) that shows that WA cannot be trusted in many cases...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{|x|^{a}|y|^{b}}{|x|^{c} + |y|^{d}}$ does not exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471552/prove-that-lim-x-y-rightarrow0-0-fracxaybxc-yd)

Answer (score 5):

Approaching $(0,0)$ along the curve $x=y^4$ you get

$$
\frac{xy^4}{x^2+y^8} = \frac{y^8}{y^8 + y^8} = \frac12
$$

which clearly does not tend to $0$ as $y \to 0$. Since you get different values along different paths, the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: I  think is $x=y^4$

Comment: @nanchangjian Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** let $x=ky^4(k\neq 0)$,so
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{xy^4}{x^2+y^8}=\dfrac{k}{k^2+1}$$

Answer (score -1):

$a=x,b=y^4=>\lim_{(0,0)}\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}=\lim_{(0,0)}\frac{a/b}{(a/b)^2+1}=$ Indeterminate, since for instance we could have various ratios between *x* and $y^4$ as they both approach $0$.

Comment: Why $\lim_0\frac{a/b}{(\frac ab)^2+1}=\lim_0\frac ab$?

Comment: We simplify both sides through $b^2$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you were asking something else. It's not, I've corrected it. The point is that a/b can be anything.